# Counting how many machines are on target in a selectable period of time

Tags: powerbi, dax, countif, measure

I am struggling with a request I got for my dashboard.
I have the table [Perf] with a list of machineID and the relative performance data. I am able to calculate some KPIs I have to monitor as measures, so I have for example KPI1 calculated per each machineID and in a selectable period of time.
Per each of these machineID I have a target. I need to count how many machineID are on target and how many are below.
I am able to graph per each machineID if it is above or below target, but I don't know how to count!!

I have tried to create a table like:

```
MTBF_Above_Spec = SUMMARIZECOLUMNS(Perf_CDASHBOARD_KPI[SerialNo], Perf_CDASHBOARD_KPI[Internal Spec. MTBF],
FILTER('InstalledBase', 'InstalledBase'[EquipmentType] = "CE_FM"), Filter(Perf_CDASHBOARD_KPI, Perf_CDASHBOARD_KPI[Internal Spec. MTBF]>0),
"MTBF", [FM MTBF])
```

where `[FM MTBF]` is the KPI1. It took more than 2 hours to calculate it and furthermore, if I change the period of time, the column doesn't change, I should refresh the table each time (and even if this is possible with some command, I cannot make the user wait two or more hours to get the result!)

Hope I was clear enough and hope someone can support me!

Answer (score 0):

If you use a slicer to select a time period, and this date is in a column of Perf_CDASHBOARD_KPI, then this should work I think: Create a knew measure

```
    Measure = CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(Perf_CDASHBOARD_KPI), Perf_CDASHBOARD_KPI[Internal Spec. MTBF]>0)
```

But I am relatively new to power bi, so I am not completely certain...

Comment: It works fine for the measure I have created, but not for the calculated table MTBF_Above_Spec. I am afraid that this is not possible at all. I found a post dated 2018 saying "Unfortunately, dynamic calculate table or dynamic calculate column are not supported by DAX" so I really think it is not possible at all... waiting for any idea!

Comment: Yes, I could only make it work with measures too. Like you said, it seems to not work dynamically for columns or tables. If you simply want the count shown in your dashbord (or a calculation with it), you can use the measure. Otherwise I don´t have an Idea eather, sorry :/